# Windows forms app to copy one file multiple times in a folder

Tags: c#, powershell, winforms

I am trying to make a small program to duplicate one file "X" (user input) times. So i created this windows forms app

[image: my windows forms app]

I am not sure how to write the code for the Start button where I can say `File.Copy` the specific file 1000 times let's say and save them in the desired folder.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            tbAlegefisierul.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lbAlegeFisierul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSalveaza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {tbSalveaza.Text = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath); }
    }

    private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
       File.Copy(tbAlegefisierul.Text, tbSalveaza.Text, true);
       MessageBox.Show("Ai copiat cu succes!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
   
    private void tbnrori_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, please consider adding code you've already tried, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-6.0

Comment: Did you design the form yourself? If so, what's the trouble with adding the box to type in the number?

Comment: Did you write `btnStart_Click` yourself?

Comment: @Enigmativity  I did the design of the form myself. My problem is that I do not know what to use instead of File.Copy to make it copy the file X times.

Comment: @IulianDochita - You absolutely use `File.Copy`. You just need to call it in a loop.

Comment: @IulianDochita - You really should have finished designing the form and then provided as much code as you could. I'll vote to re-open if you do.

Comment: @Enigmativity i tried to rewrite the question and i finished the design of the form. I hope this time people with get my question. I am sorry, i am very new to this.

Comment: Please provide as much code as possible.

Comment: In case it doesn't get re-opened: https://pastebin.com/uiHc0wmM

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity! With very few modifications.. it WORKED !!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
private string _fileName = null;
private string _selectedPath = null;
private int? _nrori = null;

private void UpdateStartButton()
{
    btnStart.Enabled =
        File.Exists(_fileName)
        && Directory.Exists(_selectedPath)
        && _nrori.HasValue
        && _nrori.Value > 0;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbAlegefisierul.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        _fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        this.UpdateStartButton();
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.UpdateStartButton();
}

private void btnSalveaza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbSalveaza.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        _selectedPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        this.UpdateStartButton();
    }
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _nrori.Value; i++)
    {
        var destinationFileName = Path.Combine(_selectedPath, $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_fileName)} ({i + 1}){Path.GetExtension(_fileName)}");
        File.Copy(_fileName, destinationFileName, true);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Ai copiat cu succes!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

private void tbnrori_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _nrori = int.TryParse(tbnrori.Text, out int n) ? (int?)n : null;
    this.UpdateStartButton();
}
```